# Regex - match a valid company name (UK regulations)

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex to match UK valid company naming standards based on [The Company Regulations 2015 - Permitted characters](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2015/17/regulation/2/made). The pattern that I am trying to match:

1. Permitted word characters and symbols may be used in any part of the name:

   `A-Z a-z 0-9 ? ! & @ \ / £ $ € ¥ . , «» -`
2. Symbols that **one type per group** may be used: *

   `" “”` - `' ‘’` - `() [] {} <>`
3. Permitted symbols **only after** the first 3 characters:

   `* = # % +`
4. 160 permitted characters max.

* To further elaborate on part 2:

> (d) any other punctuation referred to in [column 1 of table 2 in Schedule 1](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2015/17/images/uksi_20150017_en_002) but only in one of the forms set out opposite that punctuation in column 2 of that table.

This means that if a company name using parentheses `()`, it should not have squared brackets `[]` or curly brackets `{}`. It should include parentheses only. Or if a company name uses `“”`, it should not use `"`. Likewise, if a company name uses `‘’`, it should not use `'`.

---

[Here is my Regex101 with tests](https://regex101.com/r/LrdsBD/4/tests) that works for PCRE, JS, Py and Go:

```js
/^[A-Za-z0-9 \"“”'‘’()[\]{}<>«»\\\/?!&@£$€¥.,-]{3}[*=#%+A-Za-z0-9 \"“”'‘’()[\]{}<>«»\\\/?!&@£$€¥.,-]{0,157}$/
```

This regex will fail to match *part 2: one type per group rule* test case.

I can solve this without regex, But I am interested to know if it is possible to do in regex only?

Comment: Can the words in brackets appear anywhere in the string?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Yes, brackets may be used in any part of the string as per the regulation standards.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/Sy5Rtk/1

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/LrdsBD/7 , it passes all of your tests

Comment: @UnbearableLightness My bad, I thought you could still see the comments after deleting the question. I think It is not specific enough and thus not a suitable question here. I will still look into Wiktor's and your answer and do further tests as well later on.

Comment: I think the question is good actually, it's well written and could be useful to others in the future. I think it should be possible to do with a single regex...  cool, let us know.

Comment: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on [@Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3390419/) regex from the comments.

**Regex101 with further tests:**

- [PCRE (PHP)](https://regex101.com/r/LrdsBD/9/tests)
- [JavaScript](https://regex101.com/r/LrdsBD/11/tests)
- [Python](https://regex101.com/r/LrdsBD/13/tests)

**Explanation:**

[Positive lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are used to assert the string follows **part (d)** of the standard (symbols that one type per group may be used). And within, each sub-rule is separated by [atomic grouping](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) for performance.

**PCRE**

```
/^
  (?=
    (?>  [^{}()<>]*   \[+  [^{}()<>]*   \]+  [^{}()<>]*   )  *$|
    (?>  [^[\]()<>]*  \{+  [^[\]()<>]*  \}+  [^[\]()<>]*  )  *$|
    (?>  [^[\]{}<>]*  \(+  [^[\]{}<>]*  \)+  [^[\]{}<>]*  )  *$|
    (?>  [^[\]{}()]*  \<+  [^[\]{}()]*  \>+  [^[\]{}()]*  )  *$|
    (?>  [^[\]{}()<>]*                                    )  *$
  )

  (?=
    (?>  [^"]*   \“+  [^"]*   \”+  [^"]*   )  *$|
    (?>  [^“”]*  \"+  [^“”]*  \"+  [^“”]*  )  *$|
    (?>  [^"“”]*                           )  *$
  )

  (?=
    (?>  [^']*   ‘+  [^']*  ’+  [^']*   )  *$|
    (?>  [^‘’]*  '+  [^‘’]* '+  [^‘’]*  )  *$|
    (?>  [^'‘’]*                        )  *$
  )

  [A-Za-z0-9 \"“”'‘’()[\]{}<>«»\\\/?!&@£$€¥.,-]{3}
  [A-Za-z0-9 \"“”'‘’()[\]{}<>«»\\\/?!&@£$€¥.,\-*=#%+]{0,157}
$/
```

**JavaScript and Python**

JavaScript and Python do not support atomic grouping syntax. So until then, you will have to settle down with a [lookahead assertion hack to emulate atomic groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-tricks.html#pseudo-atomic-groups) that works quite well:

```
/^
  (?=
    (?=(  [^{}()<>]*   \[+  [^{}()<>]*   \]+  [^{}()<>]*   ))\1  *$|
    (?=(  [^[\]()<>]*  \{+  [^[\]()<>]*  \}+  [^[\]()<>]*  ))\2  *$|
    (?=(  [^[\]{}<>]*  \(+  [^[\]{}<>]*  \)+  [^[\]{}<>]*  ))\3  *$|
    (?=(  [^[\]{}()]*  \<+  [^[\]{}()]*  \>+  [^[\]{}()]*  ))\4  *$|
    (?=(  [^[\]{}()<>]*                                    ))\5  *$
  )

  (?=
    (?=(  [^\"]*  \“+  [^\"]*  \”+  [^\"]*  ))\6  *$|
    (?=(  [^“”]*  \"+  [^“”]*  \"+  [^“”]*  ))\7  *$|
    (?=(  [^\"“”]*                          ))\8  *$
  )

  (?=
    (?=(  [^']*   ‘+  [^']*  ’+  [^']*   ))\9   *$|
    (?=(  [^‘’]*  '+  [^‘’]* '+  [^‘’]*  ))\10  *$|
    (?=(  [^'‘’]*                        ))\11  *$
  )

  [A-Za-z0-9 \"“”'‘’()[\]{}<>«»\\\/?!&@£$€¥.,-]{3}
  [A-Za-z0-9 \"“”'‘’()[\]{}<>«»\\\/?!&@£$€¥.,\-*=#%+]{0,157}
$/
```

Hopefully, this would be useful for others.

Comment: Any developer who has to debug this little gem is just going to jump off a cliff

Comment: Neat! Happy you got everything working, glad I was of help. Well written answer. Great job on adapting the pattern for JavaScript and Python.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Cheers, thanks again for sharing your expertise. It would be nice if you re-posted this as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @1010101 No worries, happy to help. There's no need, your answer is already very comprehensive. I'm happy with the mention :)